# get data between 2 rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
id col  op  value
1  math >=   75
2  math <=   82
3  sci  =    72
4  geo  >    45
5  geo  <    50
```

select value from my_table;

I have a table like this. I want the output like 46,47..49,72,75,76,77...82 in oracle sql.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. You want the "missing" values, I suppose, but why start from `46`?

Comment: i want the values according to the op coloumns'.
like math >=75 , math <=82 , i want the values between them

Comment: still not very clear. We're not looking over you shoulder so don't know what you are trying to achieve. Explain the expected result please. How do you calculate 46,47..49,72,75,76,77...82 ? Please take some time to explain your problem rather than replying with a single sentence.

Comment: if you see my op cloumns these are operators, here geo is >45 means it starts from 46 and go up to 49 (because geo is <50).

Comment: You need to explain in the Question itself. Not in comments. It would be best if you were to show how the result should look like exactly, and why. Also how your current SQL is not doing it the way you expect.

Comment: I doubt it is possible in SQL. But you can do it in PLSQL: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=45e377a5a6508f69b98aa9701b955177).

Comment: You want the output to be one string of comma delimited numbers with no correlation to the "col" column? I could see math 76-81, sci 72, geo 46-49 ?  what is the real goal of the output here?  what will you do with it?  That will help in determining how to approach this.

Comment: @rashmiranjanrout: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62173756/edit) to show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: With geo your output is inside the range in the table, but with math the range is inclusive.  Which is it?  Or is it different for each col value?

Comment: my output should look like 46,47,48,49,72,75,76,77,.....85.

Comment: Oh i missed the <= operator. :-/

Comment: @PonderStibbons,
i m getting below error
 [Error] Execution (19: 44): ORA-06550: line 5, column 44:
PL/SQL: ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: @PonderStibbons, can I store these values and use as input in my other query.

Comment: Yes, you can change this code block into function and then select from it like here: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63f6e892a604d79cf5cd1c1ac246e44d). You can also try the answer provided by @Gary_W which looks promising and does not require function.

Comment: @PonderStibbons

error [Error] Execution (19: 44): ORA-06550: line 5, column 44: PL/SQL: ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword ORA-06550: line 5, column 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  Kind of convoluted but hopefully the comments help.  It's one query broken into steps using Common Table Expressions (CTEs). This proves it can be done but I would highly suggest finding a better way to approach your problem.

```
-- Original data
WITH tbl(ID, COL, op, val) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'math', '>=', 75 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'math', '<=', 82 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'sci',  '=',  72 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'geo',  '>',  45 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'geo',  '<',  50 FROM dual
),
-- Find the ranges based on the col and it's operator
range_tbl(ID, start_val, end_val) AS (
  SELECT ID,  
    CASE op
      WHEN '>' 
        THEN val + 1
      ELSE val
    END AS start_val,
    CASE op
      WHEN '>='
        THEN (SELECT val
              FROM tbl tbl1
              WHERE tbl1.COL=tbl.COL
              AND op = '<=')
      WHEN '>'
        THEN (SELECT val-1
              FROM tbl tbl1
              WHERE tbl1.COL=tbl.COL
              AND op = '<')     
      WHEN '='
        THEN val       
    END AS end_val
FROM tbl
),
-- "Loop" through each range using connect by
nbr_tbl(nbr) AS (
  SELECT start_val + (LEVEL-1) AS nbr
  FROM range_tbl
  WHERE end_val IS NOT NULL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (end_val - start_val)+1
    AND PRIOR ID = ID
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
)
-- Now put them into a single row using listagg
SELECT LISTAGG(nbr, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY nbr) AS nbr_list
FROM nbr_tbl
;
```

Output:

```
NBR_LIST                                                                        
-------------------------------------------
46,47,48,49,72,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82                                          
1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to output ranges, something like this?

math: 75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82

sci: 72

geo: 46,47,48,49

If so, SQL alone is the wrong tool for this.  You could use the SQL to help build a dynamic expression in another tool (PL/SQL, perhaps).

Comment: i just want the values so thta i can use this output for my other query

Comment: @michael Marks This should be in the comments under the original question as this is not an answer.

Comment: @Gary_W I don't disagree, but I can't comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fetch `min` and `max` value for the subject and generate the number as follows:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(id, col,  op,  value) AS
  2  (SELECT 1,  'math', '>=',   75 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,  'math', '<=',   82 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3,  'sci',  '=',    72 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4,  'geo',  '>',    45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 5,  'geo',  '<',    50 FROM DUAL)
  7  -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
  8  SELECT
  9  LISTAGG(V.COLUMN_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY V.COLUMN_VALUE) AS RES
 10    FROM (
 11  SELECT COL,
 12         MIN( CASE WHEN OP IN( '=', '>=') THEN VALUE
 13         WHEN OP = '>' THEN VALUE + 1
 14         END ) AS MINVAL,
 15         MAX( CASE WHEN OP IN( '=', '<=') THEN VALUE
 16         WHEN OP = '<' THEN VALUE - 1
 17         END ) AS MAXVAL
 18    FROM YOUR_TABLE
 19   GROUP BY COL) T
 20   CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
 21  SELECT T.MINVAL + LEVEL - 1
 22    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= T.MAXVAL - T.MINVAL + 1
 23  ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST) ) V;

RES
---------------------------------------------------
46,47,48,49,72,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82

SQL>
```